# What bike do I have?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, germany

I have recently purchased a bicycle from a second hand shop. It seems to have all sorts of different parts. The frame however has a badge and markings of 'Kontroll' made in West Germany. Doing some research I can't find anything about this make, is anyone familiar with this brand?

As it says West Germany this may date it to the 80's. It's a large frame which is handy as I am 6ft 6.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture or three will likely help here.

Comment: how do i add a picture to this thread?

Comment: @doug: Click "edit", then there's a convenient little  picture button (between the `{}` and '123' buttons) you can use to upload.  When you have low rep it can't be displayed inline, but somebody with higher rep can come along and fix that.

Comment: thanks for that, it all works but as you said i cant upload with my minimal rep.

Comment: Well, maybe if enough folks click this question you'll have enough rep.  Otherwise, you can put the picture on Flicker or some such and link to it.

Comment: I'd place it somewhere in the 80s or maybe early 90s.  Not a high-priced bike, though not a real cheapie either.  Maybe a brand sold at discount stores.  The frame is nicely lugged.  Can you make out a brand stamp on the derailers or the levers?

Comment: Does it say "Kontroll" somewhere else than in the third picture? Because there it stands for "control number" (used for guarantee)

Comment: I know at least two German companies starting with "K": Kettler and Kalkhoff. However a short Google search did not bring any similar symbols up.

Comment: ah maybe your right, it may not be kontroll after all. so... how do kettler and kalkhoff rate?

Comment: I think this is a Kondor frame. It was a german manufacturer   see here: http://www.fahrradsucht.de/kondor/kondor.php

Comment: "Kontroll-Nr. 862 Bei Beanstandung unbedingt angeben" - "Control Nr 862 provide with every complaint" (adding to @unor 's comment)

Comment: Not many bikes these days have a built-in acoustic guitar. This is quite the find!

Answer (score 2):

That bike is a Swabian brand from Konrad Kotter (who had until 1982 and again in 1987 the professional racing team Kotter's Racing Team) that later went over to Albuch

The Albuch Kotter logo now looks like this:

[image: Albuch Kotter Head tube logo]